# How can i solve a recursion equation with square root using recursion tree method?

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, computability, recurrence-relation

> $T(n) = \sqrt{2}T(\frac{n}{2}) + \sqrt{n}$

I am trying to solve this question by recursion tree method, do we have any way in which we can draw a recursion tree for this eqn.

I just don't want to use master or extended master theorem

Comment: I don't see a choice there, you can't solve it using Master's Theorem anyway, not in this form.

Comment: Are you required to use the recursion tree method? There may be other methods that are easier.

Answer (score 1):

If you apply the recursive formula again to $T(n/2)$ you get the following:
$$ T(n) = \sqrt{2}\cdot T(n/2) + \sqrt{n} \\T(n)= \sqrt{2}(\sqrt{2}\cdot T(n/4) + \sqrt{n/2}) + \sqrt{n} \\T(n)= 2\cdot T(n/4) + 2\sqrt{n}$$

For this formula you are now probably able to draw a recursion tree.

Comment: Unfortumately, the original post has been edited to make your answer invalid.

Comment: @RickDecker yes the edit appears to have changed the question entirely. I believe it should be edited back to match this.

Answer (score 0):

The first step is that you go and evaluate T(1024) by hand. You will find a factor $2^{27.5}$ in there and a lot more. Figure out the pattern, write down a conjecture what $T(2^k)$ would be, and prove it.